# I depressurized my canner and reprocessed jars with lids sealed. Will the food be ok?

Tags: food-safety, canning

The canner began coming to pressure, steam started shooting under the pressure gauge.

The jars began to seal when I opened the canner to fix the gasket. I reprocessed them all without putting new lids on (some were sealed), will the food still be good in those sealed jars?

Answer (score 3):

If the canner pressure *dropped* suddenly from high pressure (either because a valve or gasket failed catastrophically, or because you quick-released the pressure), I might worry about the contents having boiled up, compromising the seals. But if the canner just failed to pressurize on the first try because of a leaking gasket, I don't see any reason for concern.